# Issue with Detox (react native) running on Azure DevOps

Tags: react-native, azure-pipelines, detox

I have a few integration tests using Detox for React Native and they work fine using Release configuration on my local machine.

However, when I tried to set up the same configuration on Azure DevOps pipeline, it looks like the tests don't pass.

It looks like the Metro Bundler tries to run on new terminal window, but since it is an Azure Pipeline VM it is gets stuck? Then, the tests don't pass. Since it is a release version, maybe there is a way to block this event? The release version doesn't need the bundler to be running anyway.

My detox command:

```
detox build --configuration ios.sim.release
```

My detox configuration:

```
 "ios.sim.release": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/raio.app",
        "build": "RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js xcodebuild -workspace ios/raio.xcworkspace -scheme raio -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "device": {
          "type": "iPhone 11 Pro"
        }
      }
```

Additional question: Does anyone know how running this xcodebuild line in the terminal makes the Metro bundler to start? Is there any custom Build Phase added to xcode for react native which triggers it?

Comment: May I know how's this things going after the weekend?

Comment: Hello, Merlin, I've been kind busy with other things. I will try to do it this week. But I think your explanation really makes sense and probably a self Mac-agent will fix the issue. I will try to follow the steps and let you know once it is done! Thank you for the support so far! :)

Comment: It's okay. Just confirming is it still be issue in private agent so that I may need let our team know. Looking forward to that:-)

Comment: Hey, @MerlinLiang-MSFT, I tested it using a self agent running as LaunchAgent and it worked well! :) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this result you described is like this:

[image]

This is the limitation while you using Hosted MacOS agent ran with pipeline.

This daemon (**Metro bundler**) gets launched in separate terminal windows needs **interactive** mode, but the `Hosted MacOS agents` run as **service**. So not [interactive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service) mode this could be one reason why it is failing.

Also, until now, we haven't expand the feature on `Hosted MacOS agents` to support launch this daemon in separate terminal through build pipeline and keep it running as background process.

You'd better configure your [self Mac-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops) so that you have complete control over the machine environment.

Comment: Hi Merlin Liang - have there been any changes/updates on this? We are also running UI Tests on a React Native app through Detox on Azure DevOps on a hosted macOS agent and are having similar issues. I suspect it's because the hosted mac agents can ONLY be run as a service and not interactive?

Comment: I am trying the same thing and it is also failing. Would love to hear a solution.